# how to send money using json-rpc in bitcoin-cli for php?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

`$bitcoin->sendfrom($this->session->userdata('account'), $_POST['address'], number_format($_POST['amount'], 8));`

but this isn't working. i got everything via json-rpc. but can't send or move money using  json-rpc. what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The suggested library for Bitcoin JSON-RPC via PHP is the [EasyBitcoin-PHP](https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP) library. [Source](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#PHP)

Here's a simple example:

```
<?php 
require("easybitcoin.php");

//authenticate
$bitcoin = new Bitcoin("RPCusername", "RPCpassword"); 

//execute ternary command
$send = $bitcoin->sendtoaddress("1SomeBitcoinAddy", 1); 
echo $send ? $send : "Oops an error: ".$bitcoin->error;   
?>
```

The first argument for `sendtoaddress()` is the address you want to send funds to, the second is the amount in whole bitcoins.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(number_format($_POST['amount'], 8)>.00009){

$amount=number_format($_POST['amount'], 8);

$bitcoin->sendfrom($this->session->userdata('account'), $_POST['address'], (float)$amount);

}
else{

echo "Tumbling is not possible vai php";

}
```